# How does one detect when a JobService has "finally" failed, after all retries?

Tags: android, android-service

[JobService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html)s can be retried on failure, with a specified [backoff policy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setBackoffCriteria(long,%20int)). Note that the backoff is capped at 5 hours, so after a few attempts it's possible that the job failed "permanently" and will not be retried. How can the JobService, or any other app component detect when this has happened?

Comment: My interpretation is that the maximum duration of any single back-off is 5 hours, not that they give up completely after 5 hours. My interpretation may be incorrect, though.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of it that way. Sounds ambiguous indeed.